# GUI program/library which can open excel files and allow range selection

Tags: user-interface

I'm working on a go project for spreadsheet manipulation.

All the code of my main application is sorted, but I want to be able to add a feature where a user of my tool can select an option on the GUI, which leads to the excel file they have selected being opened, and allows them to interactively select ranges from the workbook, which are then retained and used by my tool in the rest of the program

The issue I'm finding is that, apart from a matlab library/function which can do this (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importtool.html) there don't seem to be any other options for this I can find. Using Matlab wouldn't be ideal for my purposes as I can't really compile it as an exe to be used on any computer (which is a big part of my goal)

I'm happy to try my hand at using another language in order to make use of any libraries there may be for it, particularly if they are libraries for a very commonly used language (C, C++ would be ideal)

Can anyone think of any useful examples which might be relevant to my aim?

Comment: Requests for libraries are specifically off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise, I shall answer this with what I found in case anyone else comes across this niche issue and remove all but one tag so it no longer takes the space of "on-topic questions". Thanks for correcting me barny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there were no obvious libraries perfect for this in any common language; the best option for this appears to be just using a Go library which can interact with COM to open a file and subsequently take input from interactions there, which will then have to be fed into the rest of my program

The Go Ole library seems the best for this https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole